# Access violation in OnPaint from winforms on Terminal server

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The following code crashes with Object in use elsewhere, access violation in gdiplus.dll or all kinds of nasty errors.

I immediately thought of race conditions between threads on the Bitmap object (because gdiplus isn't thread safe), except I'm not using threads at all. Furthermore the GDI count is well within limits (I removed the bmp.Dispose() before creating a new one to see if that had anything to do with it.)

It works perfectly fine on my computer but crashes on one of our terminal servers after a while.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        vx = 0.01f * rnd.NextDouble();
        vy = 0.01f * rnd.NextDouble();
    }

    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    private double vx = 0.01f;
    private double vy = 0.01f;

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.label2.Text = "Thread from timer : " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
        }

        x += vx;
        y += vy;

        if (x > 1) { vx = -vx; x = 1; }
        if (y > 1) { vy = -vy; y = 1; }
        if (x < 0) { vx = -vx; x = 0; }
        if (y < 0) { vy = -vy; y = 0; }

        this.Refresh();

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Thread from paint : " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            if (bmp != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle((int)(x * bmp.Width - 50), (int)(y * bmp.Height - 50), 50, 50));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.GetType().FullName + " - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Things that occurred:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
- Message: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
- Stacktrace: 
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
```

or

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
- Message: Object is currently in use elsewhere.
- Stacktrace: 
at System.Drawing.Image.get_RawFormat()
```

or

```
Faulting application name: TestBitmapRendering.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54ae5fce
Faulting module name: gdiplus.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18455, time stamp: 0x535b1ac9
```

or

```
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectI(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out what was happening by opening process explorer and opening the stack trace of the main thread. I was lucky it went into a deadlock so it stayed in the right spot (in case of the access violation I didn't see anything out of the ordinary).

In there I saw something odd, the top of the stack was

> BeginImage
>
> FileOpenScreenHook <-- 'ullo 'ullo what 'ave we 'ere
>
> GdiDrawImage

Turns out there's a DRM software called FileOpen (http://www.fileopen.com) installed which runs a FileOpen service and injects screen hooks in all processes.

Apparently the screen hook contains a bug when the pdf plugin is installed, either corrupting my previously made Bitmap or doing something similar to render on a different thread or something.

And because the screen hook was injected into each process, once the race condition occurred in the FileOpen service, not a single process that uses Bitmaps functioned correctly (now, this was a terminal server with 20+ users so you can imagine the flood of calls we got).

After stopping the service and killing all FileOpen processes the problem went away.

So yeah, if you suddenly have random GDI errors and nothing has changed software wise or windows update wise, it's either gdiplus or related dll's that got corrupted (sfc /scannow indicated everything was fine (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wujvq.jpg)) or some 3rd party software decided it would be a good idea to hook into each process and hijack the GDI rendering api like a rootkit.

Posting this here because this tip would have been immensely handy 4 days ago when the problems started.

Comment: If software crashes on specific PC while working without problems on others - then it's PC itself (environment, pc hardware, etc) and there are 100500+ reasons why it could happens. This is why typical solution at some point is to re-install windows.